# Interior of cartesian product is cartesian product of interiors

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have to prove that:

$$\operatorname{Int}(A\times B) = \operatorname{Int}(A)\times \operatorname{Int}(B)$$

Where $A\subset M$ and $B\subset N$, both $M$ and $N$ metric spaces.

The problem is that the exercise does not specify the metric, so I need to try to prove it using a generic metric.

If $x\in \operatorname{Int}(A\times B)$, then an open ball can be centered at $(x,y)$ such that it is contained in $A\times B$. Therefore, this open ball, $B\big((x,y),r\big)\subset A\times B$. It means that $d\big((x,y),a\big)<r$ for any $a\in A\times B$ for some $r>0$. I guess that if I can take from here that $d(x,a)<r$ and $d(y,a)<r$ I can prove thhat $\operatorname{Int}(A\times B)\subset \operatorname{Int}(A)\times \operatorname{Int}(B)$, but I still have to prove the other way around.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is true for arbitrary topological spaces (not just metrizable ones). Since $A^\circ$ is open in $M$ and $B^\circ$ is open in $N$, by definition $A^\circ\times B^\circ$ is open in $M\times N$, and clearly $A^\circ\times B^\circ\subset A\times B$. It follows that $$A^\circ\times B^\circ\subset (A\times B)^\circ. $$

Conversely, since $(A\times B)^\circ$ is open in $M\times N$, we may write
$$(A\times B)^\circ = \bigcup_\alpha (U_\alpha\times V_\alpha) $$
where each $U_\alpha$ is open in $M$ and each $V_\alpha$ is open in $N$. Moreover, $U_\alpha\subset A$ and $V_\alpha\subset B$ for all $\alpha$, so $U_\alpha\subset A^\circ$ and $V_\alpha\subset B^\circ$. It follows that
$$\bigcup_\alpha (U_\alpha\times V_\alpha)\subset A^\circ\times B^\circ. $$

Comment: shouldn't $A^\circ\times B^\circ$ be open in $A\times B$?

Comment: Since $A^\circ\subset A$ and $B^\circ\subset B$, $A^\circ\times B^\circ\subset A\times B$ so yes, $A^\circ\times B^\circ$ is open in $A\times B$.

Comment: You used that the cartesian product is open, because each set is open. How'd you prove it without using metrics and topology definitions? I didn't see it already in my course.

Comment: By definition of the product topology: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology

For finite products, this is the same as the box topology: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_topology