# How to see $A=\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x \in \mathbb{N}, y \in \mathbb{R} \}$ has empty interior?

Tags: general-topology

How to see $A=\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x \in \mathbb{N}, y \in \mathbb{R} \}$ has empty interior?

It's intuitive from the visualization of this set, since it's a set of parallel lines and lines are closed sets. But what's a formal argument for empty interioriness?

Comment: Applying a more general fact: [Interior of cartesian product is cartesian product of interiors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1726174/interior-of-cartesian-product-is-cartesian-product-of-interiors)

Answer (score 2):

Let $B(x; \epsilon) = \{y \in \mathbb R^2 : \lVert x - y \rVert_2 < \epsilon\}$ be the open ball of radius $\epsilon$ around $x$. Suppose the interior of $A$ is non-empty, in particular that $x$ is in the interior of $A$. Then $x \in A$ and there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B(x; \epsilon) \subset A$. Can you why this is impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Projections are open maps. If $A$ had non-empty interior, so would $\pi_1[A]=\mathbb{N}$ have (in $\mathbb{R}$), which it has not. So the interior of $A$ is empty.

Comment: Why does this say that $A$ has empty interior? It says that $A$ is not open, but?